# How To Mock Functions Without Class in PHP (laravel)?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, mocking

I have a Function Which is loaded by composer autoload

```html
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/SmsHelper.php",
        ]
    },
```

This File Has a smsHelper Function Which Can send SMS.

```html
<?php

if (!function_exists('sendSmsHelper')) {
    function sendSmsHelper($msisdn, $message)
    {
        ..... Codes
    }
}
```

One Of My class use this Helper and i want to write test for this class.
could some one tell me how to mock this function? because i don't want to send SMS in testing mode

Comment: Just define the function in a tests/bootstrap.php

Comment: Hi Michel! let me check your solution

Comment: i checked it Michel but i get this error : Fatal error: Cannot redeclare smsHelper() (previously declared .. composer loaded it once and not let me to rewrite it! do you have any solution for rewrite?

Comment: You have to declare the test function before your composer autoload.php is loaded, because it also loads the helper functions which then checks for `function_exists`

Comment: I know i have to load my files first ( only on testing mode )! but how to do that? is it possible from codes? or any solution to prevent composer to load files on testing mode !! or even let me rewrite some file

Answer (score 1):

As I dont see any answers I decided to Wrote about some of my researches result:
I know these are not the right answers maybe but will work

First Solution (not good one): if you are using a function in your class and want to writing a test for that class ! for mocking this type of functions you can set your test class **NameSpace** equal to the class that you want to writing test for, then you can write a function exactly the same name of specific function out of the class in your .php file.

for example :  you use date() in your class and want to mock it to return your String instead of date

```html
<?php

//namespace Tests\Unit; change this name space to that class you want to write test for
namespace yourclass namespace;

use Mockery\Mock;

function date() {
  return "2019/12/17 01:00:00";
}

class yourNameTest extends TestCase
{
    ...... you test codes
}
```

Second Solution for the functions you created ( like my smsHelper ) :

I added a SwitchCase in my smsHelper function which will check if App is on Testing mode or not , if its on testing mode I'm going to return true;

```html
    function smsHelper()
    {
        if (!App::runningUnitTests()) {
            ....... my codes
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```